# What is the knee pain beneath and under the kneecap from hiking up and down inclines?

Tags: hiking, health, injury

I've been walking for exercise for four years now, with no problems.  Now I've moved to a hilly location, and I thought the inclines, up and down, would be a great addition to my flat land walking.  In general everything is fine except I experience inflammation and pain from beneath and under my right kneecap.  I've used anti-inflammatories, ice, and rest to cure it, but I would really like to know how to prevent it.

Full disclosure - I am a fit 58 year old male and I had perhaps 25% of the cartilage removed from my right knee fifteen years ago with no problem until now.

Comment: Unfortunately, knees have many things that can go wrong. I have had inflamed cartilage, as well as plica issues. Both get better with your treatments. However, the real 'cure' is leg exercises to strengthen all the muscles around the knee so they support it better. Good luck!

Comment: Please ensure you search for related questions...

Comment: @Martin http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=knee

Comment: Related? http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/6610/2303 and may be this one too http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/7803/2303

Comment: I have osgood schlatter disease which is as you describe. It might be best to talk to your doctor. No harm can come from it.

Comment: I had osgood schlatter during adolescents, but that subsided once the calcification was completed.  My best guess is the knee is a little loose because of some cartilage removal.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to fancy a guess I'd say it sounds like you're suffering from **Patellofemoral Pain Syndrome (PFPS)**.

[*What is patellofemoral pain syndrome?*](http://www.webmd.com/pain-management/knee-pain/tc/patellofemoral-pain-syndrome-topic-overview)

Unfortunately, the only sure way to prevent it–in your situation–would be to avoid the hilly inclines. Aside from that you would likely need professional help from an athletic therapist, or surgery. There's not much by the way of solid science that tells us what the sure causes or treatments of PFPS are, so you either have to self treat through trial and error, or see a specialist.